# What are these programming terminals for a 2 kW power supply?

Tags: power-supply, power, interface

Does anyone recognize the programming terminals on the real panel of this power supply? I would like to get the 50 amps out.

It is an ATE1 made by Redfern radio, it is an old army surplus.

Going in blind I have placed a 10k resistor from the +15 to the Vp and Ven allows me to get 44 amps max into a 0.5 ohm load. Vp seems to be clamped at 7.5V, even if I drop the resistance of 10k resistor connected to it.

thanks

[image: front panel]

[image: rear panel]

Comment: Have you tried to find a manual?

Comment: I tried but no luck so far

Comment: manual would be hard to find for army supplies. If they followed vintage HP methods of PSU control, the voltage and current programming would be in x Ohms/volt and  y Ohms/Amp

Comment: You might be on to something there, however the notation is different, HP machines seem to have A1,A2,A3... etc. I am trying to operate the supply locally using the front panel. I could just be that the supply is no longer capable of the original ratings. I can get max 30V or max 42 A but would really like to get the 50 A.